# ManyToMany select query is correct and the query is viewed in console. But I cant put values into jsp

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I added many to many relationship to importers and agents table..data save successfully and middle table created...but i cannot retrieve data to my jsp ...How can i retrieve agents table data to my jsp.

My model is

```
package lk.slsi.domain;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "importers")
public class Importer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "importer_id")
    private long importerId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String importerBrc;

    private String importerVatNumber;
    private String importerName;
    private String importerAddress1;
    private String importerAddress2;
    private String importerAddress3;
    private String importerCityName;
    private String officePhoneNumber;
    private String mobilePhoneNumber;

    @Email
    private String email;

    @Email
    private String optemail1;

    @Email
    private String optemail2;

    public String getOptemail1() {
        return optemail1;
    }

    public void setOptemail1(String optemail1) {
        this.optemail1 = optemail1;
    }

    public String getOptemail2() {
        return optemail2;
    }

    public void setOptemail2(String optemail2) {
        this.optemail2 = optemail2;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "importer_agents",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "importerId")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "agentId")})
    private List<Agent> agentList;


    public String getImporterBrc() {
        return importerBrc;
    }

    public void setImporterBrc(String importerBrc) {
        this.importerBrc = importerBrc;
    }

    public String getImporterVatNumber() {
        return importerVatNumber;
    }

    public void setImporterVatNumber(String importerVatNumber) {
        this.importerVatNumber = importerVatNumber;
    }

    public String getImporterName() {
        return importerName;
    }

    public void setImporterName(String importerName) {
        this.importerName = importerName;
    }

    public String getImporterAddress1() {
        return importerAddress1;
    }

    public void setImporterAddress1(String importerAddress1) {
        this.importerAddress1 = importerAddress1;
    }

    public String getImporterAddress2() {
        return importerAddress2;
    }

    public void setImporterAddress2(String importerAddress2) {
        this.importerAddress2 = importerAddress2;
    }

    public String getImporterAddress3() {
        return importerAddress3;
    }

    public void setImporterAddress3(String importerAddress3) {
        this.importerAddress3 = importerAddress3;
    }

    public String getImporterCityName() {
        return importerCityName;
    }

    public void setImporterCityName(String importerCityName) {
        this.importerCityName = importerCityName;
    }

    public String getOfficePhoneNumber() {
        return officePhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setOfficePhoneNumber(String officePhoneNumber) {
        this.officePhoneNumber = officePhoneNumber;
    }

    public String getMobilePhoneNumber() {
        return mobilePhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setMobilePhoneNumber(String mobilePhoneNumber) {
        this.mobilePhoneNumber = mobilePhoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getImporterId() {
        return importerId;
    }

    public void setImporterId(long importerId) {
        this.importerId = importerId;
    }

    public List<Agent> getAgentList() {
        return agentList;
    }

    public void setAgentList(List<Agent> agentList) {
        this.agentList = agentList;
    }
}
```

my agent table model is

```
package lk.slsi.domain;


import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "agents")
public class Agent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "agent_id")
    private long agentId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String nic;

    private String vatNumber;
    private String name;

    private String agentAddress1;
    private String agentAddress2;
    private String agentAddress3;
    private String agentCityName;
    private String officePhoneNumber;
    private String mobilePhoneNumber;
    @Email
    private String email;

    public long getAgentId() {
        return agentId;
    }

    public void setAgentId(long agentId) {
        this.agentId = agentId;
    }

    public String getNic() {
        return nic;
    }

    public void setNic(String nic) {
        this.nic = nic;
    }

    public String getVatNumber() {
        return vatNumber;
    }

    public void setVatNumber(String vatNumber) {
        this.vatNumber = vatNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAgentAddress1() {
        return agentAddress1;
    }

    public void setAgentAddress1(String agentAddress1) {
        this.agentAddress1 = agentAddress1;
    }

    public String getAgentAddress2() {
        return agentAddress2;
    }

    public void setAgentAddress2(String agentAddress2) {
        this.agentAddress2 = agentAddress2;
    }

    public String getAgentAddress3() {
        return agentAddress3;
    }

    public void setAgentAddress3(String agentAddress3) {
        this.agentAddress3 = agentAddress3;
    }

    public String getAgentCityName() {
        return agentCityName;
    }

    public void setAgentCityName(String agentCityName) {
        this.agentCityName = agentCityName;
    }

    public String getOfficePhoneNumber() {
        return officePhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setOfficePhoneNumber(String officePhoneNumber) {
        this.officePhoneNumber = officePhoneNumber;
    }

    public String getMobilePhoneNumber() {
        return mobilePhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setMobilePhoneNumber(String mobilePhoneNumber) {
        this.mobilePhoneNumber = mobilePhoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

my repository is

```
package lk.slsi.repository;

import java.util.List;
import lk.slsi.domain.Importer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

/**
 * Created by ignotus on 2/8/2017.
 */
public interface ImporterRepository extends CrudRepository<Importer,Long> {

    @Override
    Importer save(Importer importer);

    @Override
    Importer findOne(Long importerId);

    @Override
    List<Importer> findAll();

    @Override
    void delete(Long aLong);

    @Override
    void delete(Importer importer);

    @Override
    void delete(Iterable<? extends Importer> iterable);

    @Query("select u from Importer u where u.importerVatNumber = :importerVatNumber")
    Importer getImporterByimporterVatNumber(@Param("importerVatNumber") String importerVatNumber);

    @Query("select u from Importer u inner join u.agentList where u.importerId = :importerId")
    List<Importer> findAgents(@Param("importerId") long importerId);

    @Query("select u from Importer u where u.importerId = :importerId")
    Importer getImporterByimporterID(@Param("importerId") long importerId);
}
```

my services is

```
   public List<Importer> getAllIAgents(long importerId) {
        return importerRepository.findAgents(importerId);
    }
```

My controller is

```
  @RequestMapping(path = "/viewImporter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateImporterAll(@RequestParam("importerId") long importerId, Model model) {
        slsiLogger.info("Updating user with Id [{}]", importerId);
        System.out.println("Importer id is " + importerId);
        model.addAttribute("importerDetails", importerServices.getImporterByimporterID(importerId));
        model.addAttribute("Agentsdetail", importerServices.getAllIAgents(importerId));
        return "importerEdit";
    }
```

Jsp is

```
<th width="15%">Registered Agents</th> 
<c:forEach items="${Agentsdetail}" var="Agent">
<tr>
<td>${Agent.agentList.vatNumber}</td>                                                  
</tr>                                                                 
/c:forEach>
</thead>
```

The query shows in netbeans console like this

```
Hibernate: select importer0_.importer_id as importer1_2_, importer0_.email as email2_2_, importer0_.importer_address1 as importer3_2_, importer0_.importer_address2 as importer4_2_, importer0_.importer_address3 as importer5_2_, importer0_.importer_brc as importer6_2_, importer0_.importer_city_name as importer7_2_, importer0_.importer_name as importer8_2_, importer0_.importer_vat_number as importer9_2_, importer0_.mobile_phone_number as mobile_10_2_, importer0_.office_phone_number as office_11_2_, importer0_.optemail1 as optemai12_2_, importer0_.optemail2 as optemai13_2_ from importers importer0_ inner join importer_agents agentlist1_ on importer0_.importer_id=agentlist1_.importer_id inner join agents agent2_ on agentlist1_.agent_id=agent2_.agent_id where importer0_.importer_id=?
```

How can i insert agent table values to my jsp.Please help me

Comment: Do you have a get method i.e `method = RequestMethod.GET` that show results from the database?

Comment: No I use the POST methord to load data to jsp

Comment: when i access <td>${Agent.agentList}</td> the console gives the agent table attributes =====Hibernate: select agentlist0_.importer_id as importer1_1_0_, agentlist0_.agent_id as agent_id2_1_0_, agent1_.agent_id as agent_id1_0_1_, agent1_.agent_address1 as agent_ad2_0_1_,mobile_phone_number as mobile_p7_0_1_, agent1_.name as name8_0_1_, agent1_.nic as nic9_0_1_, agent1_.office_phone_number as office_10_0_1_, agent1_.vat_number as vat_num11_0_1_ from importer_agents agentlist0_ inner join agents agent1_ on agentlist0_.agent_id=agent1_.agent_id where agentlist0_.importer_id=?

Comment: How to invoke the post method in the controller (form etc.)?

Comment: @RequestMapping(path = "/viewImporter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateImporterAll(@RequestParam("importerId") long importerId, Model model) {
        slsiLogger.info("Updating user with Id [{}]", importerId);
        System.out.println("Importer id is " + importerId);
        model.addAttribute("importerDetails", importerServices.getImporterByimporterID(importerId));
        model.addAttribute("Agentsdetail", importerServices.getAllIAgents(importerId));
        return "importerEdit";
    }

Comment: this cord is for retreive data to my jsp

Comment: Not sure if the query looks proper, so in order to double check,  trace at server side,  how many objects does the service return in that list? Also as asked already, how do you invoke the post method?  From another jsp/form? Please do not post code / logs in the comments. In case its needed, update your question.

Comment: You're missing the point of an association. You have an association between Importer and Agent. So, when you have an importer, all you need to get his agents is to call importer.getAgentList. No need to execute any other query to load the egents of an importer. So just load the importer by ID, put the importer in a request attribute, and use `<c:forEach var="agent" items="$(importer.agentList}">` to iterate over the agents of the importer. Drop the useless and horribl named findAgents and getAllIAgents methods.

Comment: And please, use a GET to display an agent, not a POST. And don't name the method updateImporterAll(), since it's used to get/display an agent. Name it, for example getAgent(). Also `Agent.getAgentId()`or `Agent.getAgentAddress()` are redundant. Just use `Agent.getId()`or `Agent.getAddress()`

Comment: Yes success...thank you for u alla...respect